# Правильная замена вида ссылки

Tags: .htaccess, php

Нужно заменить ссылку в .htaccess

Ссылка вида site.ru/download/**a_b**

Как преобразовать в

site.ru/go/load.php?**id=a&val=b**

RewriteRule ^download\/(.*)$ go/load.php?id=$1&val=$2 - так не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
RewriteRule ^download\/(.*?)_(.*?)$ go/load.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
```